Can't import standalone directive inti standalone component
I'm trying to create a directive, that can catch parent element coords and change position of child element using parent element x and y positions.
Both components are standalone and directive already imported to component. But I still got error:
✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'appMenuChildPosition' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'. [plugin angular-compiler]

So, how to import directive to component properly? Oo
My component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgIf, NgFor, TruncatePipe, LocaleConverterPipe, MenuChildPositionDirective],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.sass'],
  animations: [fadeOut]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public isLoading: boolean = true;
  public settings?: Settings;
  public error?: HttpErrorResponse;
  private isDestroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private backendService: BackendService,
    private utilsService: UtilsService
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.backendService.get_settings()
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.isDestroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (data: Settings) => this.settings = data,
        error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.error = error,
        complete: () => this.setup(this.settings)
      });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isDestroyed$.next();
    this.isDestroyed$.complete();
  }

  public open(event: MouseEvent, element: NavigationElement): void {
    const parentElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
    const rect = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    element.coords = {x: rect.left, y: rect.top};
    element.opened ? element.opened = false : element.opened = true;
  }

  private setup(settings?: Settings): void {
    this.isLoading = false;
    if (!settings) return;
    if (settings.account.bid) this.utilsService.saveItem('bid', settings.account.bid);
  }
}

My directive
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMenuChildPosition]',
  standalone: true
})
export class MenuChildPositionDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input() parentX?: number;
  @Input() parentY?: number;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['parentX'] || changes['parentY']) {
      this.adjustPosition();
    }
  }

  private adjustPosition(): void {
    console.log(this.parentX, this.parentY);
  }

}

My template
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li *ngFor="let item of settings?.nav">
          <p class="link" *ngIf="item.children" (click)="open($event, item)">{{ item.name[0] }}</p>
          <a *ngIf="!item.children" [href]="item.name[1]">{{ item.name[0] }}</a>
          <ng-container *ngIf="item.children">
            <ul [class.hide]="!item.opened" class="popup-menu" [appMenuChildPosition] [parentX]="item.coords?.x" [parentY]="item.coords?.y">
              <li *ngFor="let sub of item.children">
                <a [href]="sub.name[1]">{{ sub.name[0] }}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ng-container>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


That is because you use the syntax [appMenuChildPosition]. It tells the compiler that this is a directive expecting some input named appMenuChildPosition. Just remove the brackets and you should be good !

That was pretty simple, thank you XD. It works.
